# How to sum values of object fields when they placement in array MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

There is collection with objects each of whose includes array of objects whose fields I need to count. How the best way to do this? **I need to sum only bar2 values**

```
{
      foo: [
       { bar1: 10, bar2: 20},
       { bar1: 10, bar2: 20},
       { bar1: 10, bar2: 20},
       { bar1: 10, bar2: 20}
      ]
},

{
      foo: [
       { bar1: 10, bar2: 20},
       { bar1: 10, bar2: 20},
       { bar1: 10, bar2: 20},
       { bar1: 10, bar2: 20}
      ]
}
```

Comment: what's your expected output? @Alex

Comment: new field with a sum:  { foo: [...], sum: 80 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reduce the foo.bar2 values in each document. In MongoDB, we can achieve the result with `$reduce` agregation method:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/PKFjMtuM5yT

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      sum: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$foo",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {
            $add: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this.bar2"
            ]
          },
          
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use aggregation to find the sum of bar2 value.

```js
db.getCollection('<your collection name>').aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$foo"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        bar2SUM: {
            $sum: "$foo.bar2"
        }
    }
}])
```

below are the steps which have been followed

- `{ $unwind: "$foo" }` unwinded the data
- tried to group all the documents generated during unwinding and added up bar2 values.